# Explicitly specify additional template arguments - But I have no arguments left to specify

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-specialization

The following code does not compile under *clang* (tested with version 10.0), but compiles under *gcc* (tested with version 10.1); C++ version 14.
Which of the compilers is correct?

```cpp
template< typename T > int func(); // (1)
template< typename ... Args > int func();  // (2)
template<> int func<int>() { return 1; }
int main {
  // func<int>();  // (*)
}
```

- The error message of clang is:

  > *function template specialization `func` ambiguously refers to more than one function template; explicitly specify additional template arguments to identify a particular function template*

  My problem is, the function marked with `(1)` does not have additional template parameters, thus I cannot add additional template parameters. So, how to solve this problem?
- If I uncomment the line `(*)`, then gcc also refuses to compile this code with the message:

  > *call of overloaded `func<int>()` is ambiguous*.

Comment: You are asking which compiler is correct, but then your question states that neither of them will compile the code when you try to actually call the function. I'm a bit confused what you mean

Comment: Even without specialization you have an ambiguity. Will e.g. `func<float>()` call `(1)` or `(2)`?

Comment: @UnholySheep For me, these two behaviors are quite different. I would expect, either it compiles or not.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But I am not calling `func<float>` in my example.

Comment: If you want it to compile, you could make the second overload only match if `sizeof...(Args) > 1`, like this `template <typename... Args> std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Args) > 1), int> func();`

Comment: I'm just pointing out other flaws in the code. This flaw makes your code kind of problematic as a [mre].

Comment: I'm also very curious about your real problem that you try to solve. Right now you're showing us a solution to an (for us) unknown problem, and you ask four our help to help with your solution. But if we know the actual problem you're trying to solve then we might be able to help you better, perhaps even provide other solutions. This is what is called an [*XY problem*](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: which template do you want to specialize?

Comment: fwiw, only `(1)` and `(2)` alone are already problematic. The rest of the code just makes the issues appear, but they are present in the first two lines.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is indeed an XY problem. I am currently working on some code, which does not compile: `error: call to function 'foo` that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup` (clang). Then I made a MWE, but for some unknown reason it compiles. This is the only error I could reproduce, although I do not know whether it is connected with my original problem or not, because it seems to be a different one.
Thus, I cannot ask a question for my Y problem, because I have no clue what it is.

Comment: Its a problem in any case, whether reported as error or not. Though, it would be still interesting to know if the specialization that cannot be instantiated should be an error (my guess is that both are right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given program(even without the call) is not valid because you're trying to explicitly specialize function template `func` with information that is not enough to distinguish/disambiguate which `func` to specialize. A  gcc bug report has been submitted [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=106405).

There are 2 ways to solve this depending on which `func` you want to specialize. Note also that the function call `func<int>();` **will still be ambiguous**. The solution given below is just for specialization and not for call expression.

---

##### Method 1

> My problem is, the function marked with (1) does not have additional template parameters, thus I cannot add additional template parameters. So, how to solve this problem?

In case, you want to explicitly specialize `#1` you can solve the error by moving the explicit specialization above/before `#2` as shown below:

```
template< typename T > int func(); // (1)
template<> int func<int>() { return 1; }  //OK NOW, explicitly specialize #1
template< typename ... Args > int func();  // (2)

int main() {
  
}
```

[Working  demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e49hKaWG8)

##### Method 2

And in case you want to explicitly specialize `#2` you should add more template argument in specialization as shown below:

```
template< typename T > int func(); // (1)

template< typename ... Args > int func();  // (2)
template<> int func<int, double>() { return 1; } //OK NOW, explicitly specialize #2
int main() {
  
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nxWG6vzrd)